# Proper way to return data from a reactive DAO to the controller while using MongoDB reactive driver for Java

Tags: java, design-patterns, reactive-programming, mongodb-java, reactive-streams

I am using MongoDB reactive driver for Java. I have a DAO where I query the DB using the `find().first()` function chain which return a `Publisher<Document>`. I have to call `subscribe()` (or else the query will not actually execute) on this `Publisher` instance where I do some comparisons in the `onNext(Document)` and `onError(Throwable)` callbacks. As per my logic, I have to return some values from my function but both of these callback methods are voids.

I can create an ugly looking logic whereby I block inside the callback and set my return value as a value of `AtomicReference`, which I declare outside the callbacks, and then I return the value in the `AtomicReference`. But in doing so, I'm blocking and blocking is what I do not want to do.

**How can we query for values, compare the result and then return our own kind of result based on the comparison (all from the DAO to the Controller) in a reactive way?** 
If a design pattern that exists to do such type of operation, what is it?

I am using [Micronaut](https://micronaut.io/) as my web framework.

Comment: Transform your Publisher into an Observable/Mono, and use `.map(value -> decideWhatToReturnBaseOnValue(value))`? Which reactive library are you using?

Comment: @JBNizet Nice, I can now get back to using Singles and Maybes. Thanks, just what I needed.